# Icomoon icons (svg) not loading in Internet Explorer (ie)

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, icons, loading, pyramid

I am using Icomoon's icons for my jQuery Mobile/Python PyramidHo app. I am currently testing on localhost but the problem  also exists when I deploy. They work perfectly for Chrome and Firefox.  They do not show up in Internet Explorer 11.  As far as I can tell they are not even being loaded by Internet Explorer.

I have read as much as I could about the problem with no luck.

I have placed the following meta tag at the top of my  tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I have added the html5 shiv:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">  </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

My response has these settings:

```
response.cache_control.no_store = (bool) False
response.pragma = None
```

I'm using the icon like so:

```
            <a href="demo_home"   data-role="button"  class="mp-menu-btn">
                <span class="mp-circle mp-bg-drkblue mp-menu-btn-icon-bg"></span>
                <svg class="icon icon-home2 mp-menu-btn-icon"><use xlink:href="/static/graphics/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-home2"></use></svg>
                <span class="mp-btn-text mp-font-xlg">Demos</span>
            </a>
```

How can I get the svg file to load and the icons to show up in Internet Explorer?

**EDIT**

After doing some more debugging I can clearly see the request for the SVG icon file is not even getting to my backend pyramid server.  IE is blocking or disregarding the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've suffered through this before. IE ignores all external calls to SVG. The easy answer is to include your `<symbol>` defs in the body of your `HTML`. Since these `<symbol>`s are hidden anyway, they won't disturb any other DOM elements. Then you'll have to `xlink` to the current page.

```
<use xlink:href="#icon-home2"></use>
```

If you're sickened by muddying your beautiful page with a barrage of `<symbols>` (hey, it's a reasonable disgust), use [svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) and force IE to bend to your will.

Comment: Thanks much.  IE is such garbage.  I figured out before you answered that I needed an extra script to use SVG in IE.  Icomoon recommended 'svgxuse'.  However, I could not get it to work reliably using jquery mobile.  There was some conflict that I got tired of tracking down so I tried 'svg4everybody' and it worked the first time.  Thanks again.